# What to use to store the rows after reading from table in android

Tags: android, cursor

What is the best way to save data read from SQLiteDatabase Android, and access them using row number or column name?

Hi Below is my code that I am using to fetch the data  but I want to store the rows in some kind of dataset so that i can fetch the data using column number or name . I want to dynamically show these data in a grid in android.

```
MyDatabaseSQLHelper myDatabaseSQLHelper = new MyDatabaseSQLHelper(this);

SQLiteDatabase mySQLiteDatabase = myDatabaseSQLHelper.getReadableDatabase();

String[] projection = {
        Items._ID,
        Items.COL_ITEM_NAME,
        Items.COL_ITEM_PRICE,
        Items.COL_ITEM_QUANTITY,
        Items.COL_ITEM_AMOUNT
};

Cursor cursor = mySQLiteDatabase.query(Items.TABLE_NAME,projection,null,null,null,null,null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store all rows fetch from database you can store it in Array list of type modal class. for you your modal class could be like this

**ItemBeen.java**

```
public class ItemBeen {
     String id,itemName,itemPrice,itemQty,itemAmount;

     public String getId() {
        return id;
     }

     public void setId(String id) {
         this.id = id;
     }

     public String getItemName() {
         return itemName;
     }

     public void setItemName(String itemName) {
         this.itemName = itemName;
     }

     public String getItemPrice() {
         return itemPrice;
     }

     public void setItemPrice(String itemPrice) {
         this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
     }

     public String getItemQty() {
         return itemQty;
     }

     public void setItemQty(String itemQty) {
        this.itemQty = itemQty;
     }

     public String getItemAmount() {
        return itemAmount;
     }

    public void setItemAmount(String itemAmount) {
        this.itemAmount = itemAmount;
    }
}
```

then now in your class make method for get data from database and it store all record to array list and return that array list , like this.

```
    public ArrayList<ItemBeen> getItemList() {
        Cursor cur;
        ArrayList<itemBeen> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        cur = db.query(Items.TABLE_NAME.TBL_ITEM, projection, null, null, null, null, null);

    if (cur != null) {
        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                ItemBeen bean = new ItemBeen();
                bean.setId(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(DBConstant.TBL_ITEM.KEY_ID)));
                bean.setItemName(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(DBConstant.TBL_ITEM.KEY_ITEM_NAME)));
                bean.setItemPrice(cur.getBlob(cur.getColumnIndex(DBConstant.TBL_ITEM.KEY_ITEM_PRICE)));
                bean.setItemQty(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(DBConstant.TBL_ITEM.KEY_ITEM_TQY)));
                bean.setItemAmount(cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(DBConstant.TBL_ITEM.KEY_ITEM_AMT)));

                itemList.add(bean);
            } while (cur.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    return itemList;
}
```

Now in that class in which you want all item list in that class call this method.declare array list and fetch data.

```
ArrayList<ItemBeen> itemList = new ArrayList<ItemBeen>();
itemList = DBConstant.dbHelper.getItemList();
```

and this way in itemList contains all records.